# Node.js hashing of passwords

Tags: node.js, security, cryptography, passwords, password-hash

I am currently using the following for hashing passwords:

```
var pass_shasum = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(req.body.password).digest('hex');
```

Could you please suggest improvements to make the project safer?

Comment: Unsalted SHA is not secure.  Use bcrypt.

Comment: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Great article about securing passwords every developer should read: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I use the follwing code to salt and hash passwords.

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

exports.cryptPassword = function(password, callback) {
   bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) 
      return callback(err);

    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      return callback(err, hash);
    });
  });
};

exports.comparePassword = function(plainPass, hashword, callback) {
   bcrypt.compare(plainPass, hashword, function(err, isPasswordMatch) {   
       return err == null ?
           callback(null, isPasswordMatch) :
           callback(err);
   });
};
```

Comment: Don't use else after return, it just dont make sense. Cheers!

Comment: Could you add a link to the bcrypt library which you are using (github if possible)? Thanks.

Comment: @Tadej it was so long ago, but I suppose it's: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even check the date. Sorry. :/

Comment: There are two modules [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) and [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) for this purpose, If someone can  tell more about these two that would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

bcrypt also can be called synchronously.  Sample Coffeescript:

```
bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

encryptionUtil = 
    encryptPassword: (password, salt) ->
        salt ?= bcrypt.genSaltSync()
        encryptedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        {salt, encryptedPassword}

    comparePassword: (password, salt, encryptedPasswordToCompareTo) ->
        {encryptedPassword} = @encryptPassword(password, salt)
        encryptedPassword == encryptedPasswordToCompareTo

module.exports = encryptionUtil
```

Answer (score 6):

> bcrypt with typescript
>
> ```
> npm i bcrypt
> npm i -D @types/bcrypt
> ```

```
 import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export const Encrypt = {

    cryptPassword: (password: string) =>
        bcrypt.genSalt(10)
        .then((salt => bcrypt.hash(password, salt)))
        .then(hash => hash),
    
        comparePassword: (password: string, hashPassword: string) =>
            bcrypt.compare(password, hashPassword)
            .then(resp => resp)
    
    }
```

Exemple: Encrypt

```
const myEncryptPassword = await Encrypt.cryptPassword(password);
```

Exemple: Compare

```
const myBoolean = await Encrypt.comparePassword(password, passwordHash);
```

Answer (score 4):

Also there is bcrypt-nodejs module for node. https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs.

Previously I used already mentioned here bcrypt module, but fall into problems on win7 x64. On the other hand bcrypt-nodejs is pure JS implementation of bcrypt and does not have any dependencies at all.

Comment: Would be nice but this is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bcrypt-js package for encrypting the password.

1. Try **npm i bcryptjs**
2. var **bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')** in top.
3. To hash a password:

```js
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("B4c0/\/", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
    });
});
```

4. To check your password,

```js
// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare("B4c0/\/", hash, function(err, res) {
    // res === true
});
```

You can visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs for more information on bcryptjs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bcrypt, it secures the password using hashing.

```js
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, encrypted) => {
    user.password = encrypted
    next()
})
```

Where salt is the cost value which specifies the strength of hashing.
While logging in, compare the password using bcrypt.compare method:

```js
 bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, same) => {
      if (same) {
           req.session.userId = user._id
           res.redirect('/bloglist')
      } else {
           res.end('pass wrong')
      }
 })
```

For more info, refer to this blog: https://medium.com/@nitinmanocha16/bcrypt-and-nodejs-e00a0d1df91f

Answer (score 1):

Bcrypt isn't a bad choice, but [there are a few gotchas](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#why-scrypt):

1. It will truncate on `NUL` bytes.
2. It will truncate after 72 characters. If you're using passphrases, this might weaken your password unexpectedly.

As of October 2019, [Argon2id](https://password-hashing.net) is the optimal choice.

The preferred way of interfacing with Argon2id is through libsodium (a cryptography library that provides a lot of features). There are several bindings to choose from, but the easiest is probably [sodium-plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus).

```
const SodiumPlus = require('sodium-plus').SodiumPlus;
let sodium;
(async function(){
    if (!sodium) sodium = await SodiumPlus.auto(); // Autoload the backend

    let password = 'Your example password goes here. Provided by the user.';

    // Hashing...
    let hash = await sodium.crypto_pwhash_str(
        password,
        sodium.CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
        sodium.CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
    );
    // You can safely store {hash} in a database.

    // Checking that a stored hash is still up to snuff...
    let stale = await sodium.crypto_pwhash_str_needs_rehash(
        hash,
        sodium.CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
        sodium.CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
    );
    if (stale) {
        // Rehash password, update database
    }

    // Password verification
    let valid = await sodium.crypto_pwhash_str_verify(password, hash);
    if (valid) {
        // Proceed...
    }
})();
```

The [documentation for sodium-plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus/tree/master/docs#password-hashing-and-storage) on Github includes password hashing and storage.

Comment: This answer needs upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript you can use:

```
import { pbkdf2 } from "crypto";

export async function password2key(password: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>( (resolve, reject) => {
        pbkdf2(password, config.passwordSalt, 10000, 64, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(key.toString('base64'));
          });
    })
}
```